# Need help regarding ECS service in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-ecs

Is there any guide to upgrade the ECS service in AWS, Not updating the service in ECS but upgrading the ECS framework.

Comment: Can you specify the version you are using and to what version you have to upgrade etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by updating the amazon ecs container version on your ecs instances.

It depends on what kind of OS you use. Basically under the hood, you need to ensure the amazon ecs container pulls the latest image.
You can also specify explicit versions when you pull the image, in case you don't want the latest but want to go to a specific version.

Here the Amazon documentation for upgrade
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-update.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to ECS section in AWS Web Console and open the relevant cluster. In cluster page, you can see a tab called "ECS Instances" where you can select an Container Instance. After opening an Container Instance you can find a button called "Update Agent" which will update the ECS Agent.